# how to jquery ajax json response for loop / django

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

django model

```
class UserAlbum(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='albums')
    album_photos = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, through='AlbumPhoto')
    album_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    is_private = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-date_created']

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user}'s album [{self.album_name}]"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('album:album', args=[self.user, str(self.id)])
```

django view

```
@login_required
def get_album_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        user = request.user
        albums = user.albums.all()

    return JsonResponse(serializers.serialize('json', albums), safe = False)
```

script

```
 $("#album_list_modal_button").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "{% url 'album:get_album_list' %}",
          dataType: "json",
    
          success: function (response) {
            if (response) {
              //test
              $("#modal_body_album_list").html(response) 
              
              //loop test 1
              $.each(response, function(i, item) {       
                $("#modal_body_album_list").append(item.fields.album_name);
                });
              
              //loop test 2
              for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        $('#modal_body_album_list').append('<li>'+response[i].fields.album_name+'</li>');
                    }
            } else {
              $("#modal_body_album_list").html('None');
            }
          },
          error: function (request, status, error) {
            window.location.replace("../user/login")
          },
        });
      })
```

what i need to do is print each albums name using iteration

only test part works and printed like this.

```
[{"model": "album.useralbum", "pk": 6, "fields": {"user": 6, "album_name": "test album name1", "is_private": true, "date_created": "2021-03-26T19:20:23.571"}}, {"model": "album.useralbum", "pk": 4, "fields": {"user": 6, "album_name": "test album name2", "is_private": false, "date_created": "2021-03-18T20:30:09.575"}}]
```

i've searched and find two way of loop. But these are not working.
please help!!

Comment: The code in 'loop test 1' works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/uvw6jdnr/. Do you have a specific issue? We need more information that 'not working'. Check that the AJAX request is sent, and what its response is.

Comment: looks good to me too, add a console log into the loop to verify it is looping through the results, probably its just a display issue because u forgot the <li> </li> in loop 1

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i checked type of response. it's string. then, is the problem in django part?